# Toggling Strict mode in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I made this code because, I figured that it might be an interesting concept, and that it would be nice to see it work. It enables the toggling of strict mode in any string of code.

It even allows you to set a scope to run it through, although it does use eval.

Examples:

```
toggleableStrict("var a = 1; console.log(b) 'toggle strict'; console.log(a);")()

toggleableStrict("var a = 1; console.log(a) 'toggle strict'; console.log(a);")()
```

These produce the following functions:

```
function anonymous(_a,_b
) {

                ;with(_a) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        "use strict";
                        var a = 1; console.log(b) 
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }
                ;with(_b) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        ; console.log(a);
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }
}

function anonymous(_a,_b
) {

                ;with(_a) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        "use strict";
                        var a = 1; console.log(a) 
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }
                ;with(_b) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        ; console.log(a);
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }
}
```

Which are then wrapped in a function that is returned to the user.

### Code:

```
function toggleableStrict(code, startstrict = true) {
    const globalThis = (0, eval)('this')
    const deburr = function() {
        const b = function(a) {
                return (b) => null == a ? void 0 : a[b]
            }({
                "\u00c0": "A",
                "\u00c1": "A",
                "\u00c2": "A",
                "\u00c3": "A",
                "\u00c4": "A",
                "\u00c5": "A",
                "\u00e0": "a",
                "\u00e1": "a",
                "\u00e2": "a",
                "\u00e3": "a",
                "\u00e4": "a",
                "\u00e5": "a",
                "\u00c7": "C",
                "\u00e7": "c",
                "\u00d0": "D",
                "\u00f0": "d",
                "\u00c8": "E",
                "\u00c9": "E",
                "\u00ca": "E",
                "\u00cb": "E",
                "\u00e8": "e",
                "\u00e9": "e",
                "\u00ea": "e",
                "\u00eb": "e",
                "\u00cc": "I",
                "\u00cd": "I",
                "\u00ce": "I",
                "\u00cf": "I",
                "\u00ec": "i",
                "\u00ed": "i",
                "\u00ee": "i",
                "\u00ef": "i",
                "\u00d1": "N",
                "\u00f1": "n",
                "\u00d2": "O",
                "\u00d3": "O",
                "\u00d4": "O",
                "\u00d5": "O",
                "\u00d6": "O",
                "\u00d8": "O",
                "\u00f2": "o",
                "\u00f3": "o",
                "\u00f4": "o",
                "\u00f5": "o",
                "\u00f6": "o",
                "\u00f8": "o",
                "\u00d9": "U",
                "\u00da": "U",
                "\u00db": "U",
                "\u00dc": "U",
                "\u00f9": "u",
                "\u00fa": "u",
                "\u00fb": "u",
                "\u00fc": "u",
                "\u00dd": "Y",
                "\u00fd": "y",
                "\u00ff": "y",
                "\u00c6": "Ae",
                "\u00e6": "ae",
                "\u00de": "Th",
                "\u00fe": "th",
                "\u00df": "ss",
                "\u0100": "A",
                "\u0102": "A",
                "\u0104": "A",
                "\u0101": "a",
                "\u0103": "a",
                "\u0105": "a",
                "\u0106": "C",
                "\u0108": "C",
                "\u010a": "C",
                "\u010c": "C",
                "\u0107": "c",
                "\u0109": "c",
                "\u010b": "c",
                "\u010d": "c",
                "\u010e": "D",
                "\u0110": "D",
                "\u010f": "d",
                "\u0111": "d",
                "\u0112": "E",
                "\u0114": "E",
                "\u0116": "E",
                "\u0118": "E",
                "\u011a": "E",
                "\u0113": "e",
                "\u0115": "e",
                "\u0117": "e",
                "\u0119": "e",
                "\u011b": "e",
                "\u011c": "G",
                "\u011e": "G",
                "\u0120": "G",
                "\u0122": "G",
                "\u011d": "g",
                "\u011f": "g",
                "\u0121": "g",
                "\u0123": "g",
                "\u0124": "H",
                "\u0126": "H",
                "\u0125": "h",
                "\u0127": "h",
                "\u0128": "I",
                "\u012a": "I",
                "\u012c": "I",
                "\u012e": "I",
                "\u0130": "I",
                "\u0129": "i",
                "\u012b": "i",
                "\u012d": "i",
                "\u012f": "i",
                "\u0131": "i",
                "\u0134": "J",
                "\u0135": "j",
                "\u0136": "K",
                "\u0137": "k",
                "\u0138": "k",
                "\u0139": "L",
                "\u013b": "L",
                "\u013d": "L",
                "\u013f": "L",
                "\u0141": "L",
                "\u013a": "l",
                "\u013c": "l",
                "\u013e": "l",
                "\u0140": "l",
                "\u0142": "l",
                "\u0143": "N",
                "\u0145": "N",
                "\u0147": "N",
                "\u014a": "N",
                "\u0144": "n",
                "\u0146": "n",
                "\u0148": "n",
                "\u014b": "n",
                "\u014c": "O",
                "\u014e": "O",
                "\u0150": "O",
                "\u014d": "o",
                "\u014f": "o",
                "\u0151": "o",
                "\u0154": "R",
                "\u0156": "R",
                "\u0158": "R",
                "\u0155": "r",
                "\u0157": "r",
                "\u0159": "r",
                "\u015a": "S",
                "\u015c": "S",
                "\u015e": "S",
                "\u0160": "S",
                "\u015b": "s",
                "\u015d": "s",
                "\u015f": "s",
                "\u0161": "s",
                "\u0162": "T",
                "\u0164": "T",
                "\u0166": "T",
                "\u0163": "t",
                "\u0165": "t",
                "\u0167": "t",
                "\u0168": "U",
                "\u016a": "U",
                "\u016c": "U",
                "\u016e": "U",
                "\u0170": "U",
                "\u0172": "U",
                "\u0169": "u",
                "\u016b": "u",
                "\u016d": "u",
                "\u016f": "u",
                "\u0171": "u",
                "\u0173": "u",
                "\u0174": "W",
                "\u0175": "w",
                "\u0176": "Y",
                "\u0177": "y",
                "\u0178": "Y",
                "\u0179": "Z",
                "\u017b": "Z",
                "\u017d": "Z",
                "\u017a": "z",
                "\u017c": "z",
                "\u017e": "z",
                "\u0132": "IJ",
                "\u0133": "ij",
                "\u0152": "Oe",
                "\u0153": "oe",
                "\u0149": "'n",
                "\u017f": "s"
            }),
            c = /[\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\xff\u0100-\u017f]/g,
            d = /[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe2f\u20d0-\u20ff]/g;
        return function(a) {
            return a && a.replace(c, b).replace(d, "")
        }
    }();

    function createProxyGlobalAndUpdater(global, strict, sources) {
        strict = Boolean(strict)
        let allowed = null;
        let no_result = Symbol("no result");
        let proxy = Proxy.revocable(global, {
            get: function(target, property, receiver) {
                if (property == "this") {
                    return 1;
                } else if ((property == '_a' || property == '_b') && arguments.callee.caller == allowed) {
                    return proxy;
                } else if (property == 'addGlobalSource' && arguments.callee.caller == allowed) {
                    return (source) => {
                        sources.push(source.bind(global));
                    }
                }
                return target[property] || globalThis[property] || (deburr(String(property)).replace(/[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*/i, "") == "" ? (sources.map((source) => source(property)).filter(a => typeof a != "undefined")[0]) : undefined)
            },
            set: (target, property, value) => {
                return target[property] = value;
            },
            has: (target, property, receiver) => {
                return !strict || property in target || ((property == '_a' || property == '_b')) || ((deburr(String(property)).replace(/[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*/i, "") == "" && arguments.callee.caller == allowed ? (sources.map((source) => source(property, no_result)).filter(a => typeof a != "undefined")[0]) : undefined) != undefined)
            },
            getOwnPropertyDescriptor: (target, property) => {
                return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property)
            }
        })
        return [proxy.proxy, (a) => {
            allowed = a
        }, proxy.revoke];
    }
    let chunks = code.split(/('toggle strict'|"toggle strict")/).filter((item) => {
        return !/('toggle strict'|"toggle strict")/.test(item)
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            chunks[i] = `
                ;with(_a) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        "use strict";
                        ${chunks[i]}
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }`
        } else {
            chunks[i] = `
                ;with(_b) {
                    this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                        ${chunks[i]}
                        return (_, no_result) => {
                            try{
                                return eval(_) || no_result;
                            } catch(e) {
                                return no_result
                            }
                        }
                    })())
                }`
        }
    }
    let func = Function("_a", "_b", chunks.join(''))
    let scope_evals = [];
    let sources = [];
    let [firstProxy, firstUpdate] = createProxyGlobalAndUpdater(this, true, sources);
    let [secondProxy, secondUpdate] = createProxyGlobalAndUpdater(this, false, sources)
    firstUpdate(func);
    secondUpdate(func);
    let args = [firstProxy, secondProxy];
    let togglestrict = {
        ['toggle-strict']() {
            func.bind(firstProxy)(...args, ...arguments)
        }
    } ["toggle-strict"];
    Object.defineProperty(togglestrict, "setScopeWithEval", {
        value: function setScopeWithEval(func) {
            scope_evals.push(func)
        }
    })
    Object.defineProperty(togglestrict, "toString", {
        value: function toString() { return `function ${this.name}() { [shim code] }` }
    })
    Object.defineProperty(togglestrict.toString, "toString", {
        value: togglestrict.toString
    })
    return togglestrict;
}
```

<sub>Credits to Lodash for the deburr function</sub>

Comment: if it is throwing then it belongs on stackoverflow, not code review. that said, the fact that this contains obfuscated code and is completely unreadable means i would never use this. why would you want to toggle strict mode anyway...

Comment: @iwrestledabearonce It's throwing because you're running code that would throw anyhow... if you try `console.log(b)` without `b` defined, it **will** throw in strict mode.

Comment: And it's not obfuscated, that's the implementation of deburr

Comment: Where is `globalThis` defined? What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: globalThis is the... aww that's probably a browser thing. Might not be in node. It's the global this, or in the case of browsers, the window. Yeah, it's not in node.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Substituted `this` for `globalThis` at `return target[property] || this[property] || ..` executed `toggleableStrict("var a = 1; 'toggle strict'; console.log(a); console.log(b)")()` at `console`, result at Mozilla is `ReferenceError: b is not defined`. What is the purpose of the function? What does the code attempt to solve?

Comment: @guest271314 Do you know what strict mode is?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Yes. Though what is the ultimate purpose of the function? To insert or remove `'use strict'` into or from a function body?

Comment: The point of the function is that you can turn on and off strict mode. The point is, there are benifits to both.

Comment: Ok. I'll admit there was a bug with it erroring there. However: `toggleableStrict("var a = 1; console.log(b) 'toggle strict'; console.log(a);")()` this should error.

Comment: Cannot the function be converted to a string and the string `'use strict'` can be inserted into or removed from the function body using `RegExp`? Or does the function perform any tasks other than inserting and removing the string `'use strict'` from a given function body?

Comment: Ok. Simply adding and removing it does not work, it only pays attention to it if it is the first expression in a scope. Also, in vanilla, you can't turn on and off strict mode. The point of this, is that it creates scope proxies to mimic (and enhance) strict and loose modes of JS.

Comment: Yes, `'use strict'` can be inserted or removed from the function body using `String` and `RegExp` methods, given the current implementation uses string methods anyway? At first glance the code appears to be unnecessarily verbose. `new Function` could probably be substituted for `eval()` usage. Can you include test cases for the prospective functionality of the function at the question? Utilizing block scope https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260422/ or `try..catch..finally` could possibly be substituted for the current implementation, given the purpose of the function?

Comment: Even if you insert or remove it, you cannot toggle it while in the middle of execution. That is what this allows

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle of execution"? The function is altered before execution, correct?

Comment: No... it is not. And I just tested, block scope will not work. It toggles strict mode in the middle of execution, meaning that you exit strict mode, which you would not normally be able to do.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Not gathering the purpose of the function at the question. Yes, block scope allows separate scopes for separate functionality. Am still not sure what is meant by "in the middle of execution". The code at the OP uses string input, where `'use strict';` can be inserted into or removed from the string version of code, including insertion of block scope within the input string at any place within the string. That simplifies the necessary code to `RegExp.prototype.replace()`.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, in vanilla js, either the whole function body is strict, or the whole thing isn't. This allows you to have sections of it that are strict, and sections that are not

Comment: @FreezePhoenix What do you mean by "vanilla js"? The code at the question is ES6, where block scope can be used or not used at any portion of the code.

Comment: `{'use strict';console.log(b = 1)}` according to what you're saying, this code to the left should error. Thing is, it doesn't. Because it never enters strict mode. Because block scope is not considered a valid area to enter strict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## But why?

This is a clever trick but is terrible code.

Bad naming, poor use of appropriate declaration types `const`, `var` and `let`, full of redundant code, full of bugs, inappropriate use of logic operators (Strict equality rather than `==`) and so long winded it looks like it's deliberately obfuscated.

### Redundant

- `strict = Boolean(strict)` this is in a function only called from within. You only ever pass a boolean.
- You create a `revocable` proxy on the object `global` at the end of the function you return the `revoke` function as the third item in an array. Yet the calling function ignores the revoke function, not even keeping a reference. The function is thus never used. So why use a revocable proxy in the first place, and why return it when its not used.
- Each time you call `deburr` you create a new string, eg `deburr(String(property))` If its that important why are you not doing it within the function `deburr`
- No reason to use the name `toggle-strict`. It forces you to use bracket notation for no reason. You could have used `toggleStrict`
- Use `Object.defineProperties(` when creating several properties, rather than many lines of `defineProperty`
- Redefining a function name is redundant. `Object.definePropertie(togglestrict, "setScopeWithEval", { value: function setScopeWithEval(func) {` the second function name is not needed as yoiu do not use it at any point.
- I do not understand why you assign `togglestrict.toString` to itself??? You effectively do `togglestrict.toString.toString = togglestrict.toString;` Is here a reason??
- The whole last section is just so strange, I can not workout the reasoning. It can be replaced with just a few lines. See Example A
- The loop iterating the chunks is duplicating the string, when only the global name and the directive "use strict" change. See Example B

### Bugs.

- This code will not work in a module as modules are automatically in strict mode.
- This code will not work within a function, or javascript that is in strict mode as `with` is prohibited in strict mode.
- The `set` handler on the global proxy needs to return `true` or will throw an error in strict mode. eg `toggleableStrict("b = 2;'toggle strict';b=false;'toggle strict';b=false;")`
- When not in strict mode the `set` handler incorrectly sets false to `undefined`  `toggleableStrict("b = 2;'toggle strict';b=false;console.log('b: '+b)")()`  output `b: undefined`
- Throws syntax error for `toggleableStrict("(()=>{'toggle strict';console.log('hi there');})()");`

There are plenty more bugs, but you get the picture. I get the feeling you have not done any form of rigorous testing on this code.

### Problems.

1. Testing the code I found it hard to know if I was in strict mode or not. As it is toggled, it easy to lose track of just how many toggles had been performed.
2. Not for development. It is next to useless as a development tool as you lose the ability to trace errors effectively. I can see no reason why someone would use this in release code.
3. Unmanageable. This is so poorly written that it was next to impossible to work out what it was doing. In fact I gave up on what `deburr` does, and after seeing the proxy was a mess I did not bother going further into that. I am sure there are many more issues associated.

### Examples

Examples as referenced above

#### Example A

```
// you had...
let togglestrict = {
    ['toggle-strict']() {
        func.bind(firstProxy)(...args, ...arguments)
    }
} ["toggle-strict"];
Object.defineProperty(togglestrict, "setScopeWithEval", {
    value: function setScopeWithEval(func) {
        scope_evals.push(func)
    }
})
Object.defineProperty(togglestrict, "toString", {
    value: function toString() { return `function ${this.name}() { [shim code] }` }
})
Object.defineProperty(togglestrict.toString, "toString", {
    value: togglestrict.toString
})
return togglestrict;

//======================================================================================
// Can be writen as
return Object.defineProperties(() => { func.bind(firstProxy)(...args, ...arguments) }, {
    setScopeWithEval : {value : (func) => {scope_evals.push(func)}},
    toString : {value : () => `function toggle-strict() { [shim code] }`},
});
```

#### Example B

```
// you had
for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        chunks[i] = `
            ;with(_a) {
                this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                    "use strict";
                    ${chunks[i]}
                    return (_, no_result) => {
                        try{
                            return eval(_) || no_result;
                        } catch(e) {
                            return no_result
                        }
                    }
                })())
            }`
    } else {
        chunks[i] = `
            ;with(_b) {
                this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                    ${chunks[i]}
                    return (_, no_result) => {
                        try{
                            return eval(_) || no_result;
                        } catch(e) {
                            return no_result
                        }
                    }
                })())
            }`
    }
}

//======================================================================================
// can be
for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    chunks[i] = `
        ;with(_${i % 2 ? "b" : "a"}) {
            this.addGlobalSource((() => {
                ${i % 2 ? "" : "'use strict';"}
                ${chunks[i]}
                return (_, no_result) => {
                    try{
                        return eval(_) || no_result;
                    } catch(e) {
                        return no_result
                    }
                }
            })())
        }`;

}
```

Comment: deburr is the same function as `_.deburr`. And yes, just last night I thought of making some global that would make it possible to determine whether or not it is in strict mode... Also, the point is that the code is run outside of strict mode... so it shouldn't be subject to the restrictions of strict mode itself.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Strict mode is unavoidable in modules. Also the toggle is unusable as it adds ambiguity to the scope. Consider `toggleableStrict(`var b=2; 'toggle strict'; log(b);`)();`  It throws `b as undefined`, more dangerously `b` may be in a higher scope,  thus after the toggle you access the outer `b` not the one in the same apparent scope. However the major problem is block continuity eg `{'toggle-strict'}` throws in your function and never runs the code. Toggle is limited to top level scope only. Much easier to just use the old fashioned approach `(function(){"use strict"; log(b)})()`

Comment: Actually, that first one shouldn't log b as undefined... it accesses it as 2. And yeah, I'll have to figure out how to change the proxy. It shouldn't use 2 proxies, just 1 proxy with a flag, indicating strict or not, and exposing a function that toggles it. This would also eliminate the need to use regex, and fix the scope continuity.

Comment: I'd also have to expose an immuteable value that says whether or not it is strict.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix My bad, was meant to be `let b=2; "toggle strict"; log(b); "toggle strict"; log(b)` throws on the second log

Comment: Are you quite sure modules are by default in strict mode? It seemed to work for me.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Re modules and  strict mode acording to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: ... I wonder if that's circumventable using `eval`

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I should hope not. Strict mode will one day be all there is. It fixes a major flaw in the language. Modules are the path to removing the flaw without breaking a zillion web pages. Nobody should ever write JS that is not strict (even without the directive) and modules will enforce that rule for the betterment of the language.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just don't know why `with` is disallowed.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix The argument against `with` is weak and is based on a negative assumption it will cause confusion (AKA inept coders). The reality is that the global scope is run within a `with` block eg `with(window) { /*all JS code*/ }` so we use all the time.

Comment: Huh...  `'use strict';(0, eval)('with({}) {1}')` gives `1`... implying that you can evade strict mode with eval.